# Importing my own private package in Python/PyCharm

Tags: python, package

I made a package that bundles some utilities I'm using across projects. What's an easy way to import this package each time I start a new project?

There's some private work data stored as variables in there, so I won't be uploading it onto PyPi.

I am using Python 3.7 and PyCharm, and in Project Interpreter attempted to put the /zhou_utils/dist as a 'URL' of repositories it searches for, but it threw an error.

Another solution I saw someone present was to change their local PATH, but I don't have admin privileges on my work computer so don't know if I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in my terminal from my 2nd project worked:

`pip install -e C:\Users\Uname\PycharmProjects\zhou_utils\`